# Rails how to create Jquery flash message instead of the default rails message

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create a custom Jquery message instead of the standard rails flash message at the top of my page. I want to create a flash message near my vote up bottom.

My controller:

```
def vote_up
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  current_user.up_vote(@post)
  flash[:message] = 'Thanks for voting!'
  redirect_to(root_path, :notice => 'Tak for dit indlæg, det er nu online!')
rescue MakeVoteable::Exceptions::AlreadyVotedError
  flash[:error] = 'Already voted!'
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

My view:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <h1><%= post.titel %></h1>
  <p><%= post.body_html %></p>
  <p><%= link_to 'Vote up', stem_op_path(post.id) %> BRUGERNAVN: <%= post.user.username %> | UPVOTES: <%= post.up_votes %> | DOWN VOTES: <%= post.down_votes %> OPRETTET: <%= post.created_at.strftime("%d %B") %><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></p>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So are these are two different cases: a flash message at the top on pageloads (like here on SO) and a flash message on ajax-upvote?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Groupon-style notification** put background with alfa-channel for best look

```
#rails controller   
flash[:notice] = "Login successful!"



#rails helper
module ApplicationHelper
  def flash_notifications
    message = flash[:error] || flash[:notice]

    if message
      type = flash.keys[0].to_s
      javascript_tag %Q{$.notification({ message:"#{message}", type:"#{type}" });}
    end
  end

end



#rails layout
<%= flash_notifications -%>



#javascript code
(function( $, undefined ) {
    $.notification = function(options) {
        var opts = $.extend({}, {type: 'notice', time: 3000}, options);
        var o    = opts;

        timeout          = setTimeout('$.notification.removebar()', o.time);
        var message_span = $('<span />').addClass('jbar-content').html(o.message);
        var wrap_bar     = $('<div />').addClass('jbar jbar-top').css("cursor", "pointer");

    if (o.type == 'error') {
          wrap_bar.css({"color": "#D8000C"})
        };

        wrap_bar.click(function(){
            $.notification.removebar()
        });

        wrap_bar.append(message_span).hide()
            .insertBefore($('.container')).fadeIn('fast');
    };


    var timeout;
    $.notification.removebar    = function(txt) {
        if($('.jbar').length){
            clearTimeout(timeout);

            $('.jbar').fadeOut('fast',function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }   
    };


})(jQuery);



#css
.jbar{
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    left:0px;
    z-index:9999999;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=92); 
    opacity: 0.92;
    -moz-opacity: 0.92;
    -moz-box-shadow: #555 0px 0px 5px;
    box-shadow: #555 0px 0px 5px;
}

.jbar-top{
    top:0px;
}

.jbar-bottom{
    bottom:0px;
}

.jbar-content{
    line-height:46px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.jbar-top a.jbar-cross{
    top:8px;    
}

.jbar-bottom a.jbar-cross{
    bottom:8px;
}
```

Comment: I cannot get this working on rails3 + haml. I just see the text %Q{$.notification({ message:"my message", type:"notice" });} in my html view. I don't know actually what should $.notification translate to.

Comment: **%Q** is just a Ruby string quotation method, you can use anything else. You only need to execute **$.notification** as JS code

Answer (score 2):

It kind of depends on what you mean by a custom JQuery message.  If for example you have a partial that takes a message and renders it in some way, then you might have something like

```
<% if flash[:message] %>
    <%= render :partial => "path_to_success_partial", :locals => {:message => flash[:message]} %>
<% elsif flash[:error] %>
    <%= render :partial => "path_to_error_partial", :locals => {:message => flash[:message]} %>
<% end %>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <h1><%= post.titel %></h1>
    <p><%= post.body_html %></p>
    <p><%= link_to 'Stem op', stem_op_path(post.id) %> BRUGERNAVN: <%= post.user.username %> | UPVOTES: <%= post.up_votes %> | DOWN VOTES: <%= post.down_votes %> OPRETTET: <%= post.created_at.strftime("%d %B") %><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></p>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

and then in your partials you can have something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         //put stuff into your div here
         var errordiv = ".error";
         $(errordiv).css("border", "2px solid pink");
         $(errordiv).html(message);
         $(errordiv).animate({
             //some animation
         }, 500); 
    });
</script>
<div class="error"></div>
```

Mind you, if you want to use flash messages in your application, you should always put them in a partial somewhere and stick it in your application wide view in `layouts/application.html.erb` so you can generalize the functionality.

Comment: Your solution would the flash message appear just beside the vote up link? Or would it just appear at the top? (Where I have my flash message helper

Comment: You can put that if statement where ever you want, I just assumed you want it up top.

Comment: I want the error message to appear right beside the vote up link. Instead of having it in the top.

Comment: You have the 'vote up' button displayed for all posts, so wouldn't there be a bunch of them on the page?

Comment: Like I said before, you can stick that if statement anywhere you like, if you want it to be right beside your `Vote up` link, then you can put it there.

Comment: But would I get many error messages then? There are many posts and the flash error tag would be repeated. I was thinking about if it was possiable to position the error div where the mouse is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something like [this](http://boedesign.com/demos/gritter/). Than you can use this [gem](https://github.com/dapi/gritter_notices)

Comment: I mean something like this: http://www.amino.dk/buzz/Forside try to upvote a post

Comment: It is a really nice gem, would be great if the doc was also available on english

Answer (score 0):

I think you will struggle to get an elegent solution using `redirect_to root_path`.  Assuming your `root_path` controller action is in the same controller as `vote_up`, I'd do something like this:

```
# Assuming your root_path points to index
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end

def vote_up
  # You'll need to set up all the prerequisites for your index view here
  @posts = Post.all

  @post = @posts.detect {|post| post.id == params[:id]}
  begin
    current_user.up_vote(@post)
    redirect_to(root_url, :notice => 'Tak for dit indlæg, det er nu online!')
  rescue MakeVoteable::Exceptions::AlreadyVotedError
    @post.errors.add_to_base("Already voted!")
    render 'index'
  end
end
```

Then make your view something like this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <% if post.errors.present? %>
    <div class="posterror"><%= post.errors.full_messages.to_sentence %></div>
  <% end %>
  <h1><%= post.titel %></h1>
  <p><%= post.body_html %></p>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Then use CSS to style `div.posterror`, and / or jQuery to do some fancy effects, one of the many jQuery tooltip plugins would be a good head start to this.

Best of all would be to make `vote_up` AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the flash message in the view using flash[:notice] or flash[:error] and you use to display it in whichever you like.For instance,

```
<p id='notice'>
   <%=flash[:notice]%>
</p>
```

Comment: I am already using that flash message. Instead of the rails default flash message. I want to create a Jquery flash message that appears near the vote_up link